# Changing persistence.xml to use PostgreSQL instead of MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, postgresql, heroku

I am new here, I used this site to look for answers for a long time, but this is the first time I would like to ask a question.
I want to deploy my Spring (not Spring Boot) application using Heroku. 
I found a very nice tutorial (https://github.com/Abdallah-Abdelazim/yt-heroku-demo/blob/master/README.txt), but it only shows how to do that with a Spring Boot application. His application.properties file looks like this:

```
  spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
  spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
  spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
  spring.jpa.show-sql=false
  spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I think that what I should do is to edit my persistence.xml accordingly. I did something like this, but it didn't work:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="passwordsPersistenceUnit">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>

            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

How can I change it to make it work? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The updated tutorial link is: https://github.com/Abdallah-Abdelazim/yt-heroku-demo/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `persistence.xml` doesn't support env vars as you've discovered. You'll need to do it in code, something like:

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
Map<String, Object> configOverrides = new HashMap<String, Object>();
for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
  if (envName.contains("JDBC_DATABASE_URL")) {
    configOverrides.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", env.get(envName));
  }
}
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("prod", configOverrides);
```

Here's a related [example app](https://github.com/kissaten/hibernate-jsonb). There are also many examples in the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java) including one for Spring XML config.

Comment: Thank you. To be fair this seems to be way too complicated for me and I just decided to use Spring Boot instead and I managed to deploy my app on Heroku. It worked, but now I have another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631388/heroku-doesnt-see-css-and-static-txt-file-in-spring-boot