# Heroku doesn't see CSS and static txt file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku

I created a simple Maven web application in Spring that tests the strength of passwords and saves them to MySQL database. Then I changed it to Spring Boot so I can upload it to Heroku. 
Both versions work well on localhost:8080, but when I uploaded the Spring Boot version to Heroku, it doesn't see the CSS file nor a text file with the list of words I use to find out if the password contains any existing words in English. 
Here is the link to my app on Heroku https://passwords2.herokuapp.com 
As you can see, there are no background or font colors and there is an error as soon as it tries to find "english.txt" file which is the list of words.
Here is the link to Git Hub: https://github.com/PiotrDawidziuk/passwords2
The only difference is that in the Heroku version I changed the database options to

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

in application.properties and I added Maven dependency for PostgreSQL.
[image that shows what files I think Heroku doesn't see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZzEv.png)

Edit: I used this tutorial to deploy my app to Heroku: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RHYDNSRSOs

Comment: A link to a Youtube video is probably not of help to anybody- maybe you can report here the relevant portion of code you took from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `english.txt` will go inside a JAR and when running in Heroku your file will be inside the JAR, so try to read it as a stream, check [37233069](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233069/heroku-unable-to-find-xml-config-file) to see how to read the file as a stream. Also in the SpringBoot application, you do not need `resources` folder inside `WEB-INF`, create `css` folder inside `src\main\resources\static` and copy `stylesheet.css` file to this `css` folder. In jsps, include `stylesheet.css` like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some mix-up in your view code, it is referencing static/stylesheet.css whereas your screenshot shows the stylesheet.css in your resources folder. 
That's why you're getting a 404 (resource not found) error.

There may be some custom configuration that's causing it to work in your local environment, but I recommend you debug properly before posting here.